# Script gives database error on just one system

Tags: mysql, database, perl, centos

I am a VOIP administrator and I have script for updating directory database in Perl which was purchased from vendor before I was employed here.

The script is working fine on all of the servers except for one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/opt/asterisk/lib/";
use DBI;
use Asterisk::config;
sub trim($);
# database information
$db="kesc";
$host="sip-ho.kesc.com.pk";
$userid="foo";
$passwd="bar";
$connectionInfo="dbi:mysql:$db;$host";
$hubname = "";

# make connection to database
$dbh = DBI->connect($connectionInfo,$userid,$passwd);
# Perl trim function to remove whitespace from the start and end of the string
sub trim($)
{
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}

my $rc = new Asterisk::config  (file=>'/etc/asterisk/sip.conf',keep_resource_array=>0);
@list = $rc->fetch_sections_list();
$n = 1;
foreach (@list)
{
    if ($_ ne "general") {

        $entry = $rc->fetch_keys_hashref(section=>$_);
        while ( my ($key, @value) = each(%$entry) )
        {
            if ($key eq "callerid") {
                @vars = split('<',$value[0][0]);
                $query = "insert into directory (extension,name,hub) values (" . trim($_) . ", '" . trim($vars[0]) . "', '$hubname') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hub='$hubname'";
                $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
                $sth->execute();
            }
        }
    }
    $n++;
}
```

Now I get below mentioned error when executing it.

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Office', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hub=''' at line 1 at ./directory line 39.

I have also replaced it from other server with same MySQL version where it works perfectly.

Please guide me.

Comment: Sounds like you have a syntax error. Please [edit] your question and show the Perl code that does the database query. It's possible it doesn't use placeholders, but interpolates input directly into the SQL string. If the input contains unescaped characters or is maybe missing entirely because something else along the way goes wrong, that might be the reason. See https://xkcd.com/327/. Another reason might be that the table DDL is missing the unique/primary key that the query is referring to.

Comment: Done but same code works on all other servers.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the first 80 lines of `./directory`. At a guess, the code interpolates variables into the SQL statement instead of using placeholders as it should, and the string in one of the variables contains a single quote which throws out the quoting in the SQL. Ideally you would change the code to use placeholders instead, but you could get away with escaping any quote characters in the strings before interpolating them.

Comment: @Sherjeel: I have fixed the indentation in your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Good indentation is an important tool for understanding code and if you are expecting a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, it's only polite to make it as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the code. It is as I suspected; you really shouldn't insert values directly into an SQL statement

Change line 37, 38, and 39 to this and it should work for you

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO directory (extension, name, hub) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hub = ?';
$sth   = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute( trim($_), trim($vars[0]), $hubname, $hubname );
```

Beware that the same problem is likely to exist elsewhere in the code base, so it really should be completely reviewed

Comment: Thanks the error is gone however old code was also making an insert despite of error. :) Thank u @Borodin